# How to add characters to a variable number of fields per record in a CSV using bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to write a bash script to modify a CSV file exported from one MySQL DB to import into another MySQL DB.

Input file sample.

```
12345,This is a test description,This is a test priority,[1494372600,1494376200,1494546300,1494549900]
54321,This is a another test description,This is another test priority,[1494956700,1494958500]
```

I can also export it as the following, if it matters at all.

```
12345,This is a test description,This is a test priority,1494372600,1494376200,1494546300,1494549900
54321,This is a another test description,This is another test priority,1494956700,1494958500
```

My goal is to get it to look like the following.

```
12345,This is a test description,This is a test priority,[[1494372600,1494376200],[1494546300,1494549900]]
54321,This is a another test description,This is another test priority,[[1494956700,1494958500]]
```

The last fields in each record are pairs of start times and end times. The key here is that number of fields exported per record varies depending on how many pairs of start times and end times each record has. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)(\[.*)/,a){gsub(/[^,]+,[^,]+/,"[&]",a[2]); $0=a[1] a[2]} 1' file
12345,This is a test description,This is a test priority,[[1494372600,1494376200],[1494546300,1494549900]]
54321,This is a another test description,This is another test priority,[[1494956700,1494958500]]
```

With other awks you need to add a variable plus substr().

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!
using the first format

```
awk -F'[' '{n=split($2,a,","); s=FS; 
            for(i=1;i<n;i+=2) s=s FS a[i] "," a[i+1] "]" (i==(n-1)?"":","); 
            print $1 s}' file
```

also assuming there is no square brackets in other fields.